# Break large file line by line by BYTES :java

Tags: java, file, byte

I am trying to break a large file into separate smaller files. This files is basically a list of number each on new line. I am using the code below to separate the file based on bytes each of 20bytes. The problem I am facing is that the numbers dont remain intact. For example if the original file is

```
123
2456
3456
```

the result I am getting is

```
file1     file2          CorrectFile1    CorrectFile2
1                             123           3456
2456      3                   2456
456       23
```

This is just an example. What i need is represented by correctfile. I get that this is possible because i am breaking it using bytes. Is there any way I can achieve that (Note cant use array or anything as I have to transfer the byte over the network)

```
 public static void splitFile(File f) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("entering split file");
            int splitCounter = 1;

            int sizeOfFiles = 20; // 200kb
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

            try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(f))) {
                //String name = this.getFileNameWithoutExtension(f.getName());

                int tmp = 0; // chunk size
                while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    //File newFile = new File("f.txt");
                    String fileName = String.format("%s%03d.txt", "job",splitCounter++);
                    File newFile = new File(f.getParent(),fileName);
                    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, tmp);
                        //this.tracker.jobList.add(fileName);
                        //this.parentString = f.getParent();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I thought that I might be able to solve this using NIO.2 rather quickly (`File` is actually on the edge of deprecated); but your example code and file seems to be compiling and running fine for me. Could something be changing your file pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try StringTokenizer

The string tokenizer class allows an application to break a string into tokens. The tokenization method is much simpler than the one used by the StreamTokenizer class.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it by using [Apache FileSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileSplit.html) Api.

Its tested and optimized and very fast.